# Wifi wall volume "dimmer" switch to control chromecast audio volume

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromecast

I want to develop a wifi enabled wall volume "dimmer" switch that can control the volume on a chromecast audio.  I was thinking of using a Lutron Caseta switch and trapping the changes with a RasPi that would then control the chromecast.  I am new to this community so please direct me if this or something similar has been solved.

I have not used the Lutron... is there a better choice?  I know I can control with apps and google home already.  But I have elderly people who just want a switch on the wall.

Any suggestions?  Do I need a hub to use the Lutron or can the RasPi do it by itself?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any simple/quick and easy way to do this, but it's definitely possible.

Lutron cassetta switch should work. The dimmer can be potentially any input device. Here's a guide on setting up a knob to control volume on the raspberry pi.
https://gist.github.com/savetheclocktower/9b5f67c20f6c04e65ed88f2e594d43c1

Then it's just a matter of casting the audio to the chromecast. You can do this through the chrome app.

Alternatively, you could use the mobile apps by installing Android on your Raspberry Pi
https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/android-raspberry-pi/

Here's the link to the Chromecast API if you want to create your own app:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/audio